# How does connection pooling really work?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I am using MySqlConnector for .Net. Pooling is turned on by default. Now, as stated around the web by other concerned people, this means that I get a number of sleeping connections. My question is this:

Let's say that my server can handle 300 connections (approximately what is allowed on a 4GB RAM RDS MySql Server on AWS RDS), and let's say I have 300 connections that are asleep. When connection 301 is requested by the application, will:

a) The pool use one of the existing sleeping 300 connections for it
b) Throw a maximum connection error and deny the connection

To my understanding, A should be the answer since the pool will hand out inactive (sleeping) connections. B should be what happened if you have 300 concurrently ACTIVE connections (running queries, for example), right?

I just wanna get to the bottom of this, as max_connections = 300 is freaking me out as it seems so low.

Thanks, Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there are free connections in the connection pool and there are available connections in the MySQL server as well (you may have connections outside of your application's connection pool), your application should not get any too many connections error.

Whether 300 concurrent connections are enough for your purposes can be determined through a stress test, in which you simulate the number of on current users expected in a peak period. By optimising database connection code (open  connection just before it is needed, close it down hen it is not needed any longer) 300 concurrent database connections may easily support a lot more concurrent users.

Comment: Is a sleeping connection a free connections so what I'm looking to ask.

Comment: I mean, is what I'm looking to ask.

Comment: Free from your application's point of view. Not free from any other application's point of view that do not use your connection pool.

Comment: Thanks Shadow, my application is the only app accessing the database so I'm happy with that reply :) Thanks for your answer! This has been troubling me quite a bit. Nice to know how it works.